# Error exporting CSV file to drive from GEE

Tags: export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, debugging

I am working on a project where I cross-classify several regions with each other. In other words: I train several classifiers on imagery from different regions and classify all images of all regions with each of them. I want to examine the reached overall accuracies and therefor I need to export the reached OAs to a CSV file.
For trying if it works, I just calculated 2 OAs so far. As I tried to export them, it took forever and finally trew the following error (after calculating one hour):

*"Error: Collection, argument 'features': Invalid type. Expected type: List. Actual type: List. Actual value: [1.0] (Error code: 3)"*

Here is the corresponding (and shortened) part of my script:

```
// function to train the classifiers
function classifier(regionName) { 
  var traindat_region = trainList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return traindat_region = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(100)
    .train({
      features: traindat_region,
      classProperty: label,
      inputProperties: bands
    });
}

// training the classifier on region "LVha-1"
var LVha1_RF = classifier('LVha-1');

// classifying images of regions "LVha-1" and "LVha-2" with classifier trained on region "LVha-1"
var classified_1to01 = LVha1.select(bands).classify(LVha1_RF);
var classified_1to02 = LVha2.select(bands).classify(LVha1_RF);

// function for accuracy assessment
function confusionMatrix(regionName) {
  var testdat_region = testList.filterMetadata("region", "equals", regionName)
  return ee.ConfusionMatrix(testdat_region.classify(LVha1_RF).errorMatrix({
  actual: "class",
  predicted: "classification"
}));
}

// calling the function for the two performed classifications and simultaniously assigning the reached OAs to a variable
var OA_1to1 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix('LVha-1').accuracy());
var OA_1to2 = ee.Feature(confusionMatrix('LVha-2').accuracy());

// creating featureCollection for exporting the OAs
var FC = ee.FeatureCollection([OA_1to1],[OA_1to2])

// attempt to export the featureCollection to CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: FC,
  description: 'exportTableExample',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: We don't really do code reviews here (that's what [codereview.se] is for). If you have a specific issue, you'd need to provide the code in the Question, with specific timing information.

Comment: Alright, sorry. I will change my question as soon as I am back at the computer